# jquery input value undefined

Tags: jquery

Простое перемножение при изменении `.cc` и запись в `.mprice`.
Но почему-то не перемножает - получаю в `.mprice` "NaN". Если взять отдельно `$(this).next('.pr').val()` - будет *undefined*:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"      name="np1"  class="pr"  value="257" >   
<input type="text"      name="nc1"  class="cc" value="" >   
<input type="text"      name="ns1"  class="mprice" value="" >
<script>
    $('.cc').change('input', function() {
      $(this).next('.mprice').val($(this).next('.pr').val() *  $(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В вашем скрипте нужно использовать `prev('.pr')` вместо `next('.pr')`, а также привести получаемые значения к числовому типу:

```js
$('.cc').on('input', function() {
  $(this).next('.mprice').val( +$(this).prev('.pr').val() * +$(this).val() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="np1" class="pr" value="257">
<input type="text" name="nc1" class="cc" value="">
<input type="text" name="ns1" class="mprice" value="">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Видел только .closest и .next - оказывается, есть еще и .prev :) Спасибо

Comment: @ysmhypno, next (следующий) и prev (предыдущий) часто встречаются, и не только в jQuery.